# Error en SQL al crear una clave externa, trabajo con SQLdeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

El siguiente código me da error en SQLdeveloper de Oracle en la creación de la clave externa (cuando lo elimino funciona el resto de código)

```
CREATE TABLE familia3 (
codfamilia  NUMBER(3)    PRIMARY KEY,
denofamilia VARCHAR(50)  UNIQUE   NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE producto3(
codproducto     NUMBER(5)    PRIMARY KEY, 
denoproducto    VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL ,
unidadesminimas NUMBER(4) NOT NULL  CHECK (unidadesminimas>0),
codfamilia      NUMBER(3) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT COD_FK REFERENCES codfamilia);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un par de cosas que hacen falta para crear la llave foranea/clave externa. Tienes que indicar el tipo de restricción (`foreign key`), la columna que será la llave foranea en la tabla que estas creando (`codfamilia`) y la columna de la otra tabla a la que se hace referencia (`codfamilia`).
El código de creación de la tabla `producto3` quedaría así:

```
CREATE TABLE producto3( 
    codproducto NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY, 
    denoproducto VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
    unidadesminimas NUMBER(4) NOT NULL CHECK (unidadesminimas>0),
    codfamilia NUMBER(3) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT COD_FK foreign key (codfamilia)
    REFERENCES familia3 (codfamilia)
) ;
```